# How to export a function on another function in javascript (reactjs)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use the function handleSubmit in other file, how i can export this function?
If i try to export this function this error appear "Modifiers cannot appear here".

```
export default function LoginPage(props) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const navigate = new useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/logUser");
    const data = await response.json();
    const user = data.find(
      (user) => user.email === email && user.password === password
    );
    
    if (user) {
      // Login successful
      if (user.categoryId === 1) {
        return true;
      } else if (user.categoryId === 2) {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      setErrorMessage("Invalid email or password");
      return false;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="LoginPage"></div>
  );
}
```

I have tried to export but i can't.

Comment: You can create your own custom hook and extract the functionality you need to reuse

Comment: You can't, not least because there isn't just *one*. There's a new `handleSubmit` every time `LoginPage` is called.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to get the `handleSubmit` function out of the component like this:

```
export default function LoginPage(props) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const navigate = new useNavigate();

  const data = {email, password}

  const submitForm = () => {
    const formError = await handleSubmit(email, password);
    setErrorMessage(formError)
  }

  return (
    <div className="LoginPage">
      <button onClick={submitForm}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export const handleSubmit = async (email, password) => {
    let = errorMessage = ""; 
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/logUser");
    const data = await response.json();
    const user = data.find(
      (user) => user.email === email && user.password === password
    );
    
    if (!user) {
      errorMessage = "Invalid email or password"
    }
   return errorMessage;
};
```

Then, in other files, you can import `handleSubmit`. Note that you'll have to modify the `handleSubmit` function.

```
import {handleSubmit} from "../file/path";
```

However, I recommend you check custom hooks as well. It's the proper solution: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks

Answer (score 0):

There are **two ways** that I see:

1. Take it out of the function as the other person above says and then export it and import into your other file/component.
2. or **create a separate file for handling events logic and use that file to export and import what you need.**

This way it creates a cleaner and more understandable code base…if you weren't using the submit function anywhere else than I'd say keep it in your current component that is using it, otherwise it might be better to separate it for ease of use.